# Counter does not increase in the loop?

Tags: c, loops

I tried to run this program but I cannot understand why my counter doesn't seem to increase. How I change it to make it work?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int amt, i = 0, j = 0, k = 0, l = 0;
    printf("Enter a dollar amount : ");
    scanf("%d", &amt);
    
    while (amt >= 20) // this is wrong idk why 
        amt -= 20;
        i = i + 1;
    while (amt >= 10 && amt <= 20)
        amt -= 10;
        j++;
    while (amt >= 5 && amt <= 10)
        amt -= 5;
        k++;
    while (amt > 0 && amt < 5)
        amt -= 1;
        l++;

    printf("$20 bills : %d\n", i);
    printf("$10 bills : %d\n", j);
    printf("$5 bills : %d\n", k);
    printf("$1 bills : %d\n", l);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Warnings. Use them. See [here](https://ideone.com/BjVjtA). See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57842756).

Comment: Use braces after while loop and enclose the codes inside the block. Your counter like i++ is not place inside the block of while loop, so use curly braces and place the code inside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problems lies here:

```cpp
// What you see:       // What the compiler sees:

while (amt >= 20)      while (amt >= 20)
    amt -= 20;             amt -= 20;
    i = i + 1;         i = i + 1;
```

The result of that code will be to set `i` to one (assuming it's originally zero, which it is in your case) no matter *what* value is in `amt`.

By default, the body of a `while` (or `if` or `for` ...) is a *single* statement. You can give it a *group* of statements but you do that by enclosing them in braces:

```cpp
while (amt >= 20) {
    amt -= 20;
    i = i + 1;
}
```

In addition, you upper bound checks are not necessary here. For example, the *only* way to reach:

```cpp
while (amt >= 10 && amt <= 20)
```

is if `amt` is already less than `20`. Otherwise it never would have left the previous loop. So you code can probably be better written as:

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {
    int amt, twenties = 0, tens = 0, fives = 0, ones = 0;
    printf("Enter a dollar amount : ");
    if (scanf("%d" , &amt) != 1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Invalid input\n");
        return 1;
    }
    if (amt < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Negative input\n");
        return 1;
    }
    
    while (amt >= 20) { amt -= 20; twenties++; }
    while (amt >= 10) { amt -= 10; tens++; }
    while (amt >=  5) { amt -=  5; fives++; }
    ones = amt;

    printf("$20 bills : %d\n", twenties);
    printf("$10 bills : %d\n", tens);
    printf(" $5 bills : %d\n", fives);
    printf(" $1 bills : %d\n", ones);

    return 0;
}
```

You'll notice some other changes such as more descriptive variable names, formatting, user input checking, and keeping code small. These are not *technically* necessary but they are the result of a great many years of experience in writing (and reading code).

---

As an aside, you can also do this *without* repeated subtraction, by using integer division and remainders:

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {
    int amt;
    printf("Enter a dollar amount : ");
    if (scanf("%d" , &amt) != 1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Invalid input\n");
        return 1;
    }
    if (amt < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Negative input\n");
        return 1;
    }

    int twenties = amt / 20; amt = amt % 20;
    int tens     = amt / 10; amt = amt % 10;
    int fives    = amt /  5; amt = amt %  5;
    int ones     = amt;

    printf("$20 bills : %d\n", twenties);
    printf("$10 bills : %d\n", tens);
    printf(" $5 bills : %d\n", fives);
    printf(" $1 bills : %d\n", ones);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code

```
while (amt >= 20) // this is wrong idk why 
    amt -= 20;
    i = i + 1;
```

this seems to be  *wrong*, because, you do not have an associated block to encompass all the statement you wish to execute as loop body. In your case, the code is same as

```
while (amt >= 20) {// this is wrong idk why 
    amt -= 20;
 }
 i = i + 1;
```

You need to enclose all the statements which you want to execute as loop body in a block, like

```
while (amt >= 20) {
    amt -= 20;
    i = i + 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unlike python, C does not infer program structure from indentation: your `while` statements only include the first subsequent statement, leaving `i = i + 1;` outside the `while` statement body and executing once, unconditionally.

Here is a corrected version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int amt, i = 0, j = 0, k = 0, l = 0;

    printf("Enter a dollar amount : ");
    if (scanf("%d", &amt) != 1 || amt < 0) {
        printf("invalid input\n");
        return 1;
    }
    
    while (amt >= 20) {
        amt -= 20;
        i = i + 1;
    }
    while (amt >= 10) {
        amt -= 10;
        j++;
    }
    while (amt >= 5) {
        amt -= 5;
        k++;
    }
    while (amt > 0) {
        amt -= 1;
        l++;
    }
    printf("$20 bills : %d\n", i);
    printf("$10 bills : %d\n", j);
    printf("$5 bills : %d\n", k);
    printf("$1 bills : %d\n", l);

    return 0;
}
```

Here is a simpler version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int amt;

    printf("Enter a dollar amount : ");
    if (scanf("%d", &amt) != 1 || amt < 0) {
        printf("invalid input\n");
        return 1;
    }

    printf("$20 bills : %d\n", amt / 20);
    printf("$10 bills : %d\n", amt % 20 / 10);
    printf(" $5 bills : %d\n", amt % 10 / 5);
    printf(" $1 bills : %d\n", amt % 5);
    return 0;
}
```